# Get EditValue from control's DataBindings

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress

I have `TextEdit Control` and it is bound to a class field from Datasource, so it is looks like `EditValue - bindingSource1.MyClassField`. Can I somehow get the type of EditValue via code?

I've found that `textEdit1.DataBindings[0].BindableComponent` has EditValue that I need, but it seems to be private, and `textEdit1.DataBindings[0].BindingMemberInfo` contains only string values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to cast the bindingsource current to a DataRowView.

```
object Result = null;

DataRowView drv = bindingSource1.Current as DataRowView;
if (drv != null)
{
    // get the value of the field
    Result = drv.Row["columnName"];

    // show the type if this value
    MessageBox.Show(Result.GetType().ToString());
}
```

Since this gets the value from the bindingsource it does not matters what controls are binded to it. It will work for TextEdits just as well as for a DataGridView.

EDIT:
Another way to get the type is this :
(this will only work if EditValue is not null)

```
object test;
test = textEdit1.EditValue;
MessageBox.Show(test.GetType().ToString());
```

**EDIT:**
I found a way to find the information from the databinding, so it should also work when the EditValue of textEdit1 is still null.

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection info = textEdit1.DataBindings[0].BindingManagerBase.GetItemProperties();
string fieldname = textEdit1.DataBindings[0].BindingMemberInfo.BindingField;

MessageBox.Show(info[fieldname].Name + " : " + info[fieldname].PropertyType.ToString());
```

I found this on this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I don't have any grid, I have a lot of TextEdit controls and I need to know what type of EditValue in DataBindings lies there

Comment: this has nothing to do with a grid. This works on TextEdit just as well

Comment: just try it and see if it can help you

Comment: bindingSource.Current as DataRowView always return null, doesn't work, I see that in Current lies my class, but it can't cast in DataRowView

Comment: you said that the textedit binding is bindingSource1.MyClassField. So if the TextEdit is showing a value the bindingSource1.Current should be different from null, unless there is any code that undoes the binding somehow. I use this all the time for any kind of control never had problems

Comment: Maybe you need to cast the current as your class then

Comment: bindingSource1 contains class with lots of fields, but textEdit1 map to only one field in DataBindings, EditValue, like in picture above (I've added one), may be my question was not full enough, sorry for that, so I wondered if i can somehow without knowing any information about its binding source check the type of its DataBindings.EditValue

Comment: try declaring an variable object test; and then do test = textEdit1.EditValue. Then do MessageBox.Show(test.GetType().ToString())

Comment: I think it should work, but textEdit1.EditValue is null before form shows, and when it is shown, EditValue is not null, will try to fix it, thanks for your responses

Comment: @Potato I found a better solution and updated my answer. Please check if this works also at your end.