# How to Read the Data Binding on a Windows Forms Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I know how to data bind a control.

What is an accepted way to read the Data Binding settings in code?

In the GUI, there is a **(DataBindings)** section with **Tag** and **Text**.

Below, you can see that **(DataBindings)** has the **Text:** `_rosterBS - LastName`.

I am trying to get this Binding Source and property (i.e. read the Text value).

[image: screenshot]

In the designer,

```
// 
// txtLastName
// 
this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this._rosterBS, "LastName", true));
this.txtLastName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 32);
this.txtLastName.Name = "txtLastName";
this.txtLastName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(198, 20);
this.txtLastName.TabIndex = 1;
```

[DataBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) comes from this version of the Control class:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Defines the base class for controls, which are components with visual representation.
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
[DesignerSerializer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
[ToolboxItemFilter("System.Windows.Forms")]
public class Control : Component, IDropTarget, ISynchronizeInvoke, IWin32Window, IArrangedElement, IBindableComponent, IComponent, IDisposable
{
```

From there, I started chasing down the [IBindableComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ibindablecomponent.aspx)

```
//
// Summary:
//     Enables a non-control component to emulate the data-binding behavior of a Windows
//     Forms control.
public interface IBindableComponent : IComponent, IDisposable
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the collection of currency managers for the System.Windows.Forms.IBindableComponent.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The collection of System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase objects for this System.Windows.Forms.IBindableComponent.
    BindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }
```

Then I went chasing down `BindingContext`, but it does not look like I am getting to anything that has the information I am after.

FYI: Why do I want this? Currently, I can check the Linq-To-SQL data context for changes to prompt for save on exit, but this does not let the user know what field changed. I have a way to manually compare the original to the new version in each control, but implementing this in our entire solution suite would require manually coding each form.

Update: This is NOT for DevExpress controls.

Comment: The DataBindings of a control has a property BindingMemberInfo. For example `.DataBindings["Text"].BindingMemberInfo.BindingField` would get your the field name this control is binded to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get EditValue from control's DataBindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839836/get-editvalue-from-controls-databindings)

Comment: @GuidoG, it turns out that this `BindingField` is the *Primary Key* for the records. I am looking for a way to have the code read what field/column is bound to a control.

Answer (score 0):

Tentatively, here is something that I have come up with:

```
// Occurs when all the clients have been bound to the Windows Forms BindingSource
private void rosterBindingSource_BindingComplete(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dataDictionary != null)
    {
        _dataDictionary.Clear();
    }
    _dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Control>();
    rosterBindingSource_BindingData(this);
}

private void rosterBindingSource_BindingData(Control control)
{
    foreach (var item in control.Controls)
    {
        var ctrl = item as Control;
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            rosterBindingSource_BindingData(ctrl);
            // see what is data bound
            var bindable = item as IBindableComponent;
            if (bindable != null)
            {
                foreach (Binding binding in bindable.DataBindings)
                {
                    if (!_dataDictionary.ContainsKey(binding.PropertyName))
                    {
                        _dataDictionary.Add(binding.PropertyName, ctrl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might be the best way about it. I still need to make the binding source more generic, though.